# Show only the Dimension as KPI on Qlik Sense

Tags: qliksense, kpi

May I know if it is possible to show the Dimension instead of Measure using the KPI object on Qlik Sense.

I would like to display the [Days], which is the Day Name, where the Benefit is the highest.

I am trying to do it with the below expression, but could not obtain my desired result.

```
If([Total Benefit by Day] = Max([Total Benefit by Day]), [Days])
```

I loaded the data with two columns where [Days] shows the day name (Mon, Tue,...) and [Total Benefit By Day] shows the corresponding Benefit of the day name.

I want the KPI to show only the [Days] having the Max([Total Benefit by Day]), e.g. "Fri". Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at using the `Aggr` function in QlikSense.

```
IF(AGGR(RANK(max([Total Benefit by Day]),4),Days)=1,Days)
```